# Java threaded TCP server sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have an android client and a multithreaded Java server. The server was originally written in Python and worked great, but now that I re-wrote it in Java it doesn't seem to be working. Below is my server code. It may be worth noting that the Python implementation was not multithreaded, but I don't think I would need to change the client for that anyway.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class MultiServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket = null;

    public MultiServerThread(Socket socket) {
        super("MultiServerThread");
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            String path = "C:/Users/LandClan/Desktop/cubikal";
            int count = 0;
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

            File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                String filename = file.getName();
                String extension = filename.substring(
                        filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, filename.length());
                if ("png".equals(extension)) {
                    count += 1;
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Sending " + count + " files");
            dos.writeInt(count);
            byte[] temp = new byte[1024];
            int n = 0;
            for (File file : files) {
                String filename = file.getName();
                String extension = filename.substring(
                        filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, filename.length());
                if ("png".equals(extension)) {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                    bis.read(fileContent);
                    int dataLength = fileContent.length;
                    dos.writeInt(dataLength);
                    System.out.println(filename + " is " + dataLength
                            + " bytes long");
                    while ((dataLength > 0)
                            && (n = bis.read(temp, 0,
                                    (int) Math.min(temp.length, dataLength))) != -1) {
                        dos.write(temp, 0, n);
                        dos.flush();
                        dataLength -= n;
                    }
                    // System.out.println("Sent file "+filename);
                    fis.close();
                }
            }
            for (File file1 : files) {
                String filename = file1.getName();
                String extension = filename.substring(
                        filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, filename.length());
                if ("txt".equals(extension)) {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) file1.length()];
                    bis.read(fileContent);
                    int dataLength = fileContent.length;
                    dos.writeInt(dataLength);
                    System.out.println("file is " + dataLength + "long");
                    while ((dataLength > 0)
                            && (n = bis.read(temp, 0,
                                    (int) Math.min(temp.length, dataLength))) != -1) {
                        dos.write(temp, 0, n);
                        dos.flush();
                        dataLength -= n;
                    }
                    // System.out.println("Sent file");
                    fis.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the first part of the server

```
package server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4447);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not liten on port: 4447.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (listening) {
            new MultiServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
        }
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: it would help if you tells us what you want it to do?! and not read your code and try to understand.

Comment: it is supposed to send picture and text files from the server to the client

Comment: can you describe the problem, not working it too general.

Comment: sure, when the client connects to the server, I can see the server logic executing from the debug comments, however I don't see any activity on the client and none of my debug comments on the client get triggered, also in wireshark I am only seeing the initial connection from client to server and no other traffic, so I think it may have something to do with either how I am trying to send the data, or maybe I messed up the threaded socket thing.

Comment: The DataOutputStream never seems to get closed, and the DataInputStream is never used at all?

Comment: The best way to do this is to comment out all the business logic and simply write back a String. See if the client can respond. Then take it to a conversation. Then out in your business logic piece by piece.

Comment: Can you please tell us what it is trying to do, and what happens when "it does work".

Comment: Agree with Romain, also change the IOException to Exception in the thread, as exception thrown, null for example, will pass the catch and will not be shown (there are other ways, but I suggest this way on your case)

Comment: Cool, have added that as a proper answer, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataOutputStream never seems to get closed, and the DataInputStream is never used at all.

Get rid of the DataInputStream , and make sure you close the DataOutputStream when you have finished with it.

A good way is to add a `finally{}` block to your `try-catch`, although you'll need to declare the DataOutputStream outside of the `try-catch` so it is visible in the `finally`.

```
DataOutputStream dos = null;
try
{
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    // do stuff
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    //stacktrace etc
}
finally
{
    if (dos != null) dos.close();
}
```

This kind of stuff is always a bit ugly in Java, though upcoming versions may make it better...